# How do I update a files content using vbscript without updating it's modified date?

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

A few large sites are online with incorrect doctypes (4.0 not 4.01). I have written a script to update any files with this content but it updates the date modified for the file and I want to keep this as it's original date, is this possible in vbscript (with classic asp)?

Here is my code to simply replace the file contents:

```
' My folder root is here
FileRoot = "D:\myRootHere\"
' Now I use Persits upload because I need the impersonation setting below it
Set Upload = Server.CreateObject("Persits.Upload")
' Set impersonation to authorise file over-writing (this is correct and working)
Upload.LogonUser "localhost","myUsername","myPassword"
Set Dir = Upload.Directory(FileRoot & "*.asp", SORTBY_TYPE)
For Each item in Dir
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(FileRoot & item.FileName, ForReading)
    strText = objFile.ReadAll
    objFile.Close
    If instr(strText,"HTML 4.0 Transitional") then
        strNewText = Replace(strText,"HTML 4.0 Transitional","HTML 4.01 Transitional")
        Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(FileRoot & item.FileName, ForWriting)
        objFile.WriteLine strNewText
        objFile.Close
    End If
Next
Set Upload = nothing
```

Comment: You want to update the file without the filesystem knowing about it?  I'm _guessing_ it's not possible (without some really low-level code anyway, directly modifying filesystem data), or at the very least not a good idea.  Out of curiosity, _why_ don't you want the filesystem to know that a file has been modified?  It sounds like the root of the problem is somewhere else in the design.

Comment: Hi David - I like to see mod dates as a reminder where I made significant changes to code previously and match them against my offline copy as a couple of other developers who also work on the sites and I want to make sure everything is in sync. I wondered if I could read the mod date, then write the mod date as I write to the file?

Comment: It sounds like the file modification date isn't what you should be using.  It doesn't track "significant" changes to a file, it tracks *any* changes to a file.  Your source control system should internally track what those changes actually were (and who made them, when they were made, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

I took this example from [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.03.heyscriptingguy.aspx?pr=PuzzleAnswer)

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

Set objFolder = objShell.NameSpace(FilePath)
Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName(FileName)

objFolderItem.ModifyDate = "01/01/2013 8:00:00 AM"
```

And tested ok on a file inside a folder with `Everyone` having `Full Control`